# file_put_contents() not writing to file

Tags: php

I can't seem to identify why when the client IP is present, it doesn't append to the file.

I've run echo statements all the way up until `file_put_contents()` function and I can see contents in the variable.

```
$file = 'log.txt';

$now  = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i');

if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){ 
    $log = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' '. $timestamp;
}else{
    $log = 'SERVER '.$timestamp;
}

$log = strval($log); //convert to string
$log .= "\n\r";

file_put_contents($file,$log,FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Obvious question here... do you have write permissions on log.txt?

Comment: Did you check permissions on the file?

Comment: You should always be checking the return value of `file_put_contents` to see if it returns FALSE.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on')` at the top of your file, this should give you an error.

Comment: I think you guys are onto something about the permissions. Checking now.

Comment: Spoke to the Admin who made changes which caused the file to be recreated without the right permissions. Sorted.

Answer (score -2):

First, you ask this question, it means you have not mastered basic debugging methods.

Debugging code need to open error reports. By adding 
    error_reporting (E_ALL); 
    ini_set ('display_errors', 'on');
at the beginning of the code or modify the php configuration file 
    error_reporting = E_ALL
    display_errors = On
can do that.

Unable to write to the file are usually because of a permissions problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I know this comment is over 6 years old, but what an ignorant comment (how was said).  You can also surround your code with a quick try and catch echoing $e->getMessage().  I find this useful with building SPAs.

Answer (score -4):

You need to open the file before you can write into the file, here try something like this-

```
    <?php
$my_file = fopen("log.txt", "r+");
    ?>
```

you can even do a check to see if the file is in existences as well, if it doesn't you can create it!

here is a page that might help you out

[File opening for php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: `file_put_contents` does not require fopen or fclose: http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php